# Why to music producers not bother with CD-TEXT

Tags: audio-cd

I still like CDs, buy one from a shop and slip it into my car, easy - no encoding, file transfers etc etc...

CD-TEXT has been around for a LONG time, but I have only ever come across 1 or 2 albums / singles where the producer bothers to put the CD-TEXT data on the disk. 
Given that it is a simple, open and free thing to do, and nearly all CD players (home and car) support displaying of CD-TEXT data, why is it not more widely used?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really answerable since I don't think there is any technical reason, they just don't bother.  Any particular guess as to why they don't is just that, speculation.  Someone might be able to share for one location if they were part of a decision not to, but that only applies to their case, so this is really very opinion based and not specifically answerable.  Also, hello to a fellow Photography member.

Comment: It could well be guess-based - however sometimes simple things like this have a real reason, like copyright or licensing etc. And hi!

Answer (score 2):

The only answers I could quickly find are that they either don't think about it, don't want to have to deal with clients that supplied incorrect track information, have a duplication house who's software can't support it (apparently there are some errors in one of the major pieces of software used by duplication companies) or think that the CD-TEXT data can result in a slightly slower cue time on the CD.

Comment: All of these sound like plausible reasons but without any real evidence they're just speculation.

Comment: @WarriorBob - agreed.  I put them there as everything I could gather about it.  There was some evidence I found about the duplication house software error, but fundamentally I don't think this question is definitively answerable as I don't think there is a definitive reason. (Which is also why I simultaneously voted to close as primarily opinion based.)  I just generally try to be as helpful as I can be unless there is a better answer already.  Not expecting any upvotes on this as it isn't a good answer, just better than nothing.  :)

Comment: I understand, and that is indeed why I didn't upvote (although I didn't downvote either). I *do* think it's answerable though, if someone can provide some reasonable citation such as an interview with someone in the industry who would be in a position to know. Edit: [kind of like this question](http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/898/95).